# psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type text

Tags: python, sql, string, postgresql, where-clause

`SELECT id FROM answers_schoolpaper WHERE 'string' ~* '\y(?:'|| LOWER(keys)|| ')\y'`

psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type text

Answer (score 1):

You probably need parentheses around the concatenated string, to help Postgres properly parse the expression as a single predicate:

```
SELECT id 
FROM answers_schoolpaper 
WHERE 'string' ~* ('\y(?:'|| LOWER(keys)|| ')\y')
```